# Handling Csrf in Spring Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, csrf-token

I am wanting to handle csrf in Spring Gateway application but I do not see a csrf token generated in the response headers in either the preflight request or the subsequent GET request. I read up and found that I needed to use WebFluxSecurity to secure the application.

This is my Webflux security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/helloworld/*").permitAll()
            .and().csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
.httpBasic().disable();

            ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this, I also have a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

This will cause the token to be generated and it will be added automatically

```
@Component
class AddCsrfHeaderFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        Mono<CsrfToken> tokenMono = (Mono<CsrfToken>) exchange.getAttributes().get(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        if (tokenMono != null) {
            return tokenMono.flatMap(token -> chain.filter(exchange)); // When the application subscribes to this
            // producer, it causes the token to be generated, and it is automatically added to the response
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```